# Handle Authorization Header in IIS

Tags: iis, azure-web-app-service

I would migrate from Azure Web App Linux (PHP application , apache server ) to Azure Windows App Service (IIS) and i 'am confused about handling authorization header in IIS

In `.htaccess` , i simply putting these lignes , and the Application work fine.

```
   # Handle Authorization Header
   # RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
   # RewriteRule .* - [E=Authorization:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

I try to import these rules in hosted IIS server, but it's look `IIS` unable to convert them.

So can someone can help me?

Regards.

Comment: Configure a PHP app for Azure App Service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-php?pivots=platform-linux

Comment: Already check this article , but it's look no talking about my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When use linux webapp, you need `.htaccess` file. But in windows, you need add `web.config`, becase your webapp host on `IIS`.

In linux, you use below code.

```
# Handle Authorization Header
# RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
# RewriteRule .* - [E=Authorization:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

## In Windows.

I think below is you want.

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />        
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Authorization" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```